# Update 1.7 class to 1.12.2 spigot

Tags: java, minecraft

i am trying to update a 1.7 class to 1.12.2. i fixed some errors but i dont know how to fix the other errors. if anyone have a suggestion, i would be very very happy...

The Class:

```
package de.beastsoup.utils.spigot.bo2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import de.beastsoup.utils.spigot.BeastUtils;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.TileEntity;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftWorld;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class BO2 {

private Arena arena;

public BO2() {
    this.arena = new Arena(this);
}

public Arena getArena() {
    return arena;
}

private static HashSet<Location> blocksForUpdate = new HashSet<>();

public void addBlockUpdate(Location location) {
    blocksForUpdate.add(location);
}

public void startUpdate() {
    new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!blocksForUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.World world = ((CraftWorld) Bukkit.getWorlds().get(0)).getHandle();
                for (Location location : blocksForUpdate) {
                    world.notify(location.getBlockX(), location.getBlockY(), location.getBlockZ());
                }
                blocksForUpdate.clear();
            }
        }
    }.runTaskTimer(BeastUtils.getPlugin(BeastUtils.class), 1, 1);
}

/* Spawn BO2 */

public List<Block> spawn(Location location, File file) {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    BufferedReader reader;
    ArrayList<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.contains(",") || !line.contains(":")) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            String[] coordinates = parts[0].split(",");
            String[] blockData = parts[1].split("\\.");

            setBlockFast(location.getWorld(), location.getBlockX() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[0]), location.getBlockY() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[2]), location.getBlockZ() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[1]), Integer.valueOf(blockData[0]), blockData.length > 1 ? Byte.valueOf(blockData[1]) : 0);
            blocks.add(location.getWorld().getBlockAt(location.getBlockX() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[0]), location.getBlockY() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[2]), location.getBlockZ() + Integer.valueOf(coordinates[1])));
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("BO2 spawnada em " + (time - System.currentTimeMillis()) + "ms");
    return blocks;
}

/* Load BO2 file */

public List<FutureBlock> load(Location location, File file) {
    BufferedReader reader;
    ArrayList<FutureBlock> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.contains(",") || !line.contains(":")) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] parts = line.split(":");
            String[] coordinates = parts[0].split(",");
            String[] blockData = parts[1].split("\\.");
            blocks.add(new FutureBlock(location.clone().add(Integer.valueOf(coordinates[0]), Integer.valueOf(coordinates[2]), Integer.valueOf(coordinates[1])), Integer.valueOf(blockData[0]), blockData.length > 1 ? Byte.valueOf(blockData[1]) : 0));
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return blocks;
}

/* Set methods */

public boolean setBlockFast(World world, int x, int y, int z, int blockId, byte data) {
    if (y >= 255 || y < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.World w = ((CraftWorld) world).getHandle();
    net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Chunk chunk = w.getChunkAt(x >> 4, z >> 4);
    boolean b = data(chunk, x & 0x0f, y, z & 0x0f, net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Block.getById(blockId), data);
    addBlockUpdate(new Location(Bukkit.getWorlds().get(0), x, y, z));
    return b;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean setBlockFast(Location location, Material material, byte data) {
    return setBlockFast(location.getWorld(), location.getBlockX(), location.getBlockY(), location.getBlockZ(), material.getId(), data);
}

private boolean data(net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Chunk that, int i, int j, int k, net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Block block, int l) {
    int i1 = k << 4 | i;

    if (j >= that.b[i1] - 1) {
        that.b[i1] = -999;
    }

    int j1 = that.heightMap[i1];
    net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Block block1 = that.getType(i, j, k);
    int k1 = that.getData(i, j, k);

    if (block1 == block && k1 == l) {
        return false;
    } else {
        boolean flag = false;
        net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.ChunkSection chunksection = that.getSections()[j >> 4];

        if (chunksection == null) {
            if (block == net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.Blocks.AIR) {
                return false;
            }

            chunksection = that.getSections()[j >> 4] = new net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.ChunkSection(j >> 4 << 4, !that.world.worldProvider.g);
            flag = j >= j1;
        }

        int l1 = that.locX * 16 + i;
        int i2 = that.locZ * 16 + k;

        if (!that.world.isStatic) {
            block1.f(that.world, l1, j, i2, k1);
        }
        if (!(block1 instanceof IContainer)) {
            chunksection.setTypeId(i, j & 15, k, block);
        }
        if (!that.world.isStatic) {
            block1.remove(that.world, l1, j, i2, block1, k1);
        } else if (block1 instanceof IContainer && block1 != block) {
            that.world.p(l1, j, i2);
        }
        if (block1 instanceof IContainer) {
            chunksection.setTypeId(i, j & 15, k, block);
        }
        if (chunksection.getTypeId(i, j & 15, k) != block) {
            return false;
        } else {
            chunksection.setData(i, j & 15, k, l);
            if (flag) {
                that.initLighting();
            }
            TileEntity tileentity;

            if (block1 instanceof IContainer) {
                tileentity = that.e(i, j, k);
                if (tileentity != null) {
                    tileentity.u();
                }
            }
            if (!that.world.isStatic && (!that.world.captureBlockStates || (block instanceof net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.BlockContainer))) {
                block.onPlace(that.world, l1, j, i2);
            }

            if (block instanceof IContainer) {
                if (that.getType(i, j, k) != block) {
                    return false;
                }
                tileentity = that.e(i, j, k);
                if (tileentity == null) {
                    tileentity = ((IContainer) block).a(that.world, l);
                    that.world.setTileEntity(l1, j, i2, tileentity);
                }

                if (tileentity != null) {
                    tileentity.u();
                }
            }

            that.n = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

/* FutureBlock Utils */

public class FutureBlock {
    private Location location;
    private int id;
    private byte data;

    public FutureBlock(Location location, int id, byte data) {
        this.location = location;
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public byte getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void place() {
        location.getBlock().setTypeIdAndData(id, data, true);
    }
}

}
```

This Error i need fix now: https://gyazo.com/cb3176c9d879532adddfc5ce1edad2eb , https://gyazo.com/014047f5103fd1eaace121bc121fa8dc , https://gyazo.com/6b546cd147037a9deffad42e3b1ce1ef

if anyone know nms spigot 1.12.2 or something i would be happy

Comment: I would recommend you having a look into the [spigot-api](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/overview-summary.html) and search for the function that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that third image (I don't see an error in it), and you're going to look at the Spigot docs for specific information on how to fix these, but I *can* tell you that they're related to vanilla moving from an `X`,`Y`,`Z` position (specified as 3 separate ints) to a BlockPos system (specified as a single class instance containing the 3 ints, along with various helper methods, such as `up()` and `east()`).

Both of the first two images/errors are that the method you're calling needs a `BlockPos` passed and you're giving it three ints.

I don't know where the ints are coming from in the second, and for the first, I don't know what Spigot's `Location` object is or where those values are coming from and how they're constructed.

But this should give you enough information to resolve these types of errors on your own now.